# redirect before loading URL

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm developing a node.js app where I'm using passport to build OAuth authentication system. I can access the user through request object in each resource load after configurating it. But my question is: How can I do to check before every URL load - resources defined with app.get('/', function(..) {...}) - if user is loged and redirect the client if it's not loged. I could do it just adding a test in every method, but this is not what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a middleware that checks whether the user is logged in.

```
isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.user)
    return next(); // All good, let the route handler process the request.
  else
    res.redirect('/login'); // Not logged in.
}
```

And to use it on every route that needs to be logged in:

```
app.get('/something', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  // Only in here if the user is authenticated.
});
```

You can also use the middleware on every route, by doing `app.use(isAuthenticated)`, but you will need to have extra logic in the method to not create infinite redirect loops to `/login`, etc.

Comment: I've packaged up this functionality into [connect-ensure-login](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login).  It also has convenient options for returning the user to the page they originally requested after logging in.